# How do I reset / disable radio buttons when text input ('Other') is selected?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have a form where the user can choose between: '7 days',  '14 days', '30 days' and a text input field 'Other':

```html
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="paymentperiod">Payment period</label>
          <div class="col-5">
        <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="week" >7 days </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod"  formControlName="paymentperiod" value="tweeweken">14 days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="vierweken" >30 days</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        Other:
        <input  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.paymentperiod.errors && form.controls.paymentperiod.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.paymentperiod.errors}"
                id="paymentperiod"  class="form-control" type="text" name="paymentperiod" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Other" formControlName="paymentperiod"/>
        <ul class="help-block">
          <li *ngIf="form.controls.paymentperiod.errors?.required && form.controls.paymentperiod.dirty">This field is required</li></ul>

      </div>
    </div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="kmfacturatie">kmfacturatie</label>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="kmfacturatie" formControlName="kmfacturatie" value="ja" >true</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="kmfacturatie"  formControlName="kmfacturatie" value="nee">false</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I want that radio boxes to be reset or disabled when the user clicks on the 'Other' field, so the user wont be confused. How can I achieve this? So if the user clicks on a radio button, the text input field also gets reset. I have looked on several pages but it didnt help . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a little javascript to do this.

```js
function reset(){

let radios = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');
   for(var i = 0; i< radios.length;i++){
      let input = radios[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
      
      if(input[0].name === 'paymentperiod')input[0].checked = false;
   
   }
}

function reset2(){

 document.getElementById('paymentperiod').value = '';

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="paymentperiod">Payment period</label>
          <div class="col-5">
        <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="week" onclick='reset2()' >7 days </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod"  formControlName="paymentperiod" value="tweeweken" onclick='reset2()'>14 days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="vierweken" onclick='reset2()'>30 days</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        Other:
        <input  onclick='reset()'[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.paymentperiod.errors && form.controls.paymentperiod.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.paymentperiod.errors}"
                id="paymentperiod"  class="form-control" type="text" name="paymentperiod" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Other" formControlName="paymentperiod"/>
        <ul class="help-block">
          <li *ngIf="form.controls.paymentperiod.errors?.required && form.controls.paymentperiod.dirty">This field is required</li></ul>

      </div>
    </div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="kmfacturatie">kmfacturatie</label>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="kmfacturatie" formControlName="kmfacturatie" value="ja" >true</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="kmfacturatie"  formControlName="kmfacturatie" value="nee">false</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will this erase all the radio buttons' values? Because i have more choices

Comment: I updated the solution,  It will now only erase the radio's whose name is paymentperiod.  Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: your updated answer causes all radio buttons to reset

Comment: that is strange.. because mine keeps resetting. I have added the radio buttons that keeps resetting to my post.. please have a look

Comment: It only resets the the inputs whose name = paymentperiod.  check the snippet again, you'll see I added another radio button with a different name and that one doesn't get reset. also I added the erase other input box when a radio is pressed

Comment: I added your new html.  It all seems to work fine in the snippet.  What problem are you having?

Comment: are you willing to have a quick look via Teamviewer?

Comment: sure.  I can do that now if you want

Comment: the problem was the function being named 'reset', it caused my whole form to be reset . I renamed it to 'resett' and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use Jquery to do it.Here the code. it worked perfectly when I tried it.
You need to put the jquery library in the same folder as the html page

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="paymentperiod">Payment period</label>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="week" class="boutton">7
        days </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="tweeweken"
          class="boutton">14 days</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="paymentperiod" formControlName="paymentperiod" value="vierweken"
          class="boutton">30 days</label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    Other:
    <input
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.paymentperiod.errors && form.controls.paymentperiod.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.paymentperiod.errors}"
      id="paymentperiod" class="form-control" type="text" name="paymentperiod" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Other"
      formControlName="paymentperiod" />
    <ul class="help-block">
      <li *ngIf="form.controls.paymentperiod.errors?.required && form.controls.paymentperiod.dirty">This field is
        required</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="kmfacturatie">kmfacturatie</label>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="kmfacturatie" formControlName="kmfacturatie" value="ja">true</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="kmfacturatie" formControlName="kmfacturatie" value="nee">false</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-control").focus(function () {
      $(".boutton").attr("disabled", true);
    });
    $(".form-control").blur(function () {
      $(".boutton").attr("disabled", false);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That’s great. If this works for you please accept the answer so others know it works